# How to map on Hibernate using annotations a Join with other fields with a specific value?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have an entity A, and an entity B.
The entity B is and three. And the entity A is always link with just one entity B.

Below represents this relationship as a tree:

```
A1
+-B1
 +-B2
 +-B3
 | +-B4
 |
 +-B5
 +-B6
   +-B7
     +-B8
```

And here is the data as it is stored on the database to represent the Entity B:

```
#    parent_id    entity_a_id    name
1    null         1              B1
2    1            1              B2
3    1            1              B3
4    3            1              B4
5    1            1              B5
6    1            1              B6
7    6            1              B7
8    7            1              B8
```

I want to map on the entity A to bring the root entity B, it means that I want to bring the entity B where entity_a_id is the same as the current (probably mappedBy) and the parent_id is null. 
Until now I didn't found how to add a custom query to a relationship (parent_id is null). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the requirement correctly, you  want to restrict the relationship field to contain only certain entities based on criteria. In this case you might find [**Hibernate filters**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html) useful.

**EDIT**: Hibernate also features the `@Where` annotation for conditional joins, Take a look at [**This simple example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805322/hibernate-custom-join-clause-on-association)

Comment: I think that's it! I'll try this and if it works I'll tell you.

Comment: @endrigoantonini - there is also a different possibility which may fit even better - the `@Where` annotation - AFAIK, the filters are applied session-wide, while conditional joins are not.