# dynamic joincolumn and join clause with variables

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have a unidirectional one-to-one relation. what I want to achieve is either

- create a join on clause using CASE and sending variables to it so that I can change the join column (any other suggestions to change join column are also welcomed)
- ignore the first clause created by hibernate and create specific ON clause using criteria as in the bottom of the question.

My query that works in SQL Manager:

```
SELECT d.Description, d.AccountId, d.PartnerId, a.FormattedName FROM 
InvoiceDesigns d 
INNER JOIN UserAccount a
ON 
    a.id =
    CASE 
        WHEN d.PartnerId != -1 AND d.AccountId = 1 THEN d.PartnerId
        WHEN d.PartnerId = 1 THEN d.AccountId 
        ELSE 1
    END
WHERE
d.AccountId = 1 OR PartnerId = 1
```

**The working query runs in SQL Manager, not in hibernate.** it is the thing I want to achieve, I want hibernate to create a query like this.
When an account, lets say ID = 1 to stick with example, displays designs they will see
**A)** PartnerId of design is NOT -1 AND AccountId is 1, which means it is created by a partner for that account and will display partner's formattedName.
This is for normal accounts when viewing their avaiable designs. If a partner created a design for them, they will see that partner's name.

**B)** PartnerId equals to ID of the account, which means it is a Partner design and formattedName of the account related design is created for will be displayed.
This is for partner accounts to view designs they created.

**C)** Design is created by the account directly, so will display its own name. For normal accounts and self created designs.

Normal join is working fine in hibernate when I want to use only the AccountId or PartnerId but I need to change the column to get the related FormattedName. I tried @Where, @Filter, @JoinColumnOrFormula but I wasn't able to achieve this query.

My classes with @Where basically look like this:

Design class:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    int id;

    @Column(name="AccountId")
        int accountId;

    @Column(name="PartnerId")
        int partnerId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "AccountId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = true)
    @Where(clause = "CASE " +
                            "WHEN PartnerId != -1 AND AccountId = :accountId THEN PartnerId " +
                            "WHEN PartnerId = :accountId THEN AccountId " +
                            "ELSE :accountId " + 
                        "END")
    AccountData account;
```

Account class:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
int id;

@Column(name="FormattedName")
String formattedName;
```

Here you can see that I want to send an ID to query as parameter using ":accountId" which will be used to define the join column.

this question: [custom join clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805322/hibernate-custom-join-clause-on-association) actually does something similar. That is why I focused on where clause

Addition: I also found something with criteria

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(InvoiceDesignData.class, "design");
            criteria.createCriteria("design.account", "acc", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.eqProperty("acc.id", "design.partnerId"));

            invoiceDesignList = criteria.list();
```

But this does not ignore the first condition and adds an additional condition to ON clause using AND. I removed join columns from @one-to-many hoping to ignore first condition but it does not. Produced query:

```
from InvoiceDesigns this_ left outer join UserAccount acc1_ on this_.account_id=acc1_.id and ( acc1_.id=this_.PartnerId )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? From your initial description, it sounds like you have an InvoiceDesigns table which can be joined to the UserAccount table by one of two columns - either the partnerId column, or the accountId column. You have said that this query is working. Then you are saying that you want to pass the accountId in as a parameter? Why is this? Surely for any given InvoiceDesigns object, the mechanism for joining to its related UserAccount is already defined.

Comment: I updated my question. Hope it is more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving the case statement:

```
SELECT  d.Description, d.AccountId, d.PartnerId, a.FormattedName 
FROM    (SELECT *, CASE 
                WHEN PartnerId != -1 AND AccountId = 1 THEN PartnerId
                WHEN PartnerId = 1 THEN AccountId 
                ELSE 1
            END AS SmartID
         FROM InvoiceDesigns) d 
        INNER JOIN UserAccount a
        ON a.id = d.SmartID
WHERE d.AccountId = 1 OR PartnerId = 1
```

EDIT: This basically leaves you with a straightforward join with an in-line query without a conditional ON statement.

Comment: I need to check the query and its cost of inner select there, if it is not much I will accept this one

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to map each Design to a single AccountData object, with a single join, but you want to join on either the accountId or partnerId depending on their values, then you should be able to do this by using a join formula. You'll want something like:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas(
    { @JoinColumnOrFormula(
        formula = @JoinFormula(
         value = "case " +
                 "when partnerId != -1 and accountId = 1 then partnerId" +
                 "when partnerId = accountId then accountId " +
                 "else 1" +
                 "end", 
         referencedColumnName="id")) }
)
```

Note that you need to use the @ManyToOne annotation, even though this is really a one to one association. The join formula won't work if you try to use it on a one to one.

Then you can simply retrieve the data with a normal HQL join:

```
SELECT d.description, d.accountId, d.partnerId, a.formattedName FROM Design d 
inner join d.account a
```

Comment: problem with this approach is that I will have 2 joins while I can do it with only 1. this is a VERY busy database and I must lower my query costs much as I can

Comment: I've changed the answer to show you how you can map the join using a formula which contains the case statement, so it will only perform a single join